# dialogue between two user control based on user events

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

In an ASP.NET page I have added two user control with a dropdownlist each one. The selection of a dropdownlist should be changed the query to the second user control.

What is the most efficient way to pass the selected value of dropdownlist to the second?

I initially thought of creating a public event (public string OnClientSelectedIndexChanged) while the first user control and outsource through a public string SelectedValue the selected value of the second user control:

```
public string SelectedValue
{
  get
  {
    rcg.SelectedValue return;
  }
  set
  {
    rcg.SelectedValue = value;
  }
}
```

rcg is the dropdownlist.

Could be corrected or have alternatives?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is maybe to use AJAX.
Surround the two dropdownlist with an ASP update panel and trigger this one with the first dropdownlist 'OnSelectedIndexChanged'. In the event's code you can bind your second dropdownlist..

Like this it is not necessary to reload the entire page for each first dropdownlist change..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on right track.

1: You expose an event from UC1(e.g. uc1ddlchanged) and a property from UC2 (e.g. uc1ddlSelectedValue).

2: In the OnSelectedIndexChanged of ddl1 in UC1 your raise the event uc1ddlchanged.

3: On your page that has UC1 and UC2 you handle this event and set the UC2.uc1ddlSelectedValue = UC1.SelectedValue

4: In the UC2 -> uc1ddlSelectedValue -> set{} you can set the value and rebind your ddl and or do any other thing needed to update the UC2.